# Lipschitz continuity of singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, continuity

How smooth are the singular values of a matrix $F$ in terms of entries of $F$? I am hoping for Lipschitz continuity, but was not able to find it.

Comment: I think the extreme (i.e smallest and largest) singular-values are $1$-Lipschitz functions of the input matrix (w.r.t operator norm). This can be seen via the variational characterization of these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The singular values of $F$ are the (square roots of ) eigenvalues of $F F^t,$ and the regularity of the latter have been studied half-to-death. See either T. Kato (perturbation theory of linear operators, ch. 1) or Golub-van Loan (Matrix Computations -- they almost certainly talk about singular values directly, without going through eigenvalues, but at worst talk about eigenvalues).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Corollary 8.6.2. in Golub-van Loan gives exactly Lipschitz continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Check these references

- Dmitri Alekseevsky, Andreas Kriegl, Mark Losik, Peter W. Michor, *[Choosing roots of polynomials smoothly](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9801026)*, Israel J. Math **105** (1998) 203–233, math.CA/9801026,
- Andreas Kriegl, Mark Losik, Peter W. Michor, *[Choosing roots of polynomials smoothly, II](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208228)*, Israel J. Math. **139** (2004) 183–188, math.CA/0208228.

Answer (score 0):

Since this got bumped to the front page...

Let $\sigma_i$ be the singular values of $A$ and $\tilde{\sigma}_i$ be those of $A+E$. Then, $|\sigma_i - \tilde{\sigma_i}| \leq \|E\|$, by [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_for_singular_values). That gives you 1-Lipschitz continuity.